# Communicate programmically with the ripple wallet

Tags: ripple, ripple-api

I have installed ripple server using the instructions from the below link

https://github.com/filidorwiese/ripple-wallet

Now its working in server. I can communicate with the server through command line. But what i need is communicate the server via programically. i tried to communicate the wallet using different plugins, but unfortunately everything fails. Can anyone please suggest me a plugin and also give me a solution to overcome the connection problem?
I have one more doubt how can i know in which port the ripple wallet is running? how can i set the port for the wallet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Ripple RPC server.
RPC runs on HTTP(S) protocol, so it's quite easy to call RPC methods and get a response.

Comment: Can you provide a link in using Ripple RPC server.

Answer (score 0):

> There are many types of creating Ripple Server, choose according to
>   your need

https://ripple.com/build/rippled-setup/#types-of-rippled-servers

> **Create your Ripple server using Linux**

https://ripple.com/build/rippled-setup/#installing-rippled

> Basic Communication using RPC

https://ripple.com/build/rippleapi/#boilerplate